# Why are Nvidia proprietary drivers not visible on Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 19.04

The recommended Nvidia driver for my card (1050ti) is 435.12.  However, I cannot get any proprietary drivers to show up in the Additional Drivers list, nor can I install the Nvidia binary package directly.

So far, this is a clean Ubuntu 19.04 install, with the exception that I've disabled Wayland (made no difference).

[image: where are the nvidia proprietary drivers?]

Update: I manually added `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` but still it did not show me the correct proprietary driver packages.

Comment: The 435 are not there yet for 19.04. You can install 430.

Comment: So are there no proprietary drivers for 19.04?  I get a lot of glitching with the open source versions.

Comment: All these drivers 430, etc are proprietary. the app shows them as open-source because they are from a PPA.

Comment: Oh, that's confusing.  Well, thanks for the assist!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)

Comment: This is not a duplicate question.  These questions show how to install the drivers. I know how to install the drivers.  In this case, the drivers listed are incorrectly listed as "open source" when they are in fact proprietary.