# Why is Nvidia 430 missing from the offical repos and the ppa for 19.04 when its available in 18.04?

Tags: nvidia, ppa, 19.04, repository

So the comments is this question [Unable to get nvidia running on ubuntu 18.04.2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1174172/unable-to-get-nvidia-running-on-ubuntu-18-04-2?noredirect=1#comment1959582_1174172) led me to this ask this one

When I did a fresh install of 19.04 (Kubuntu)  I had to add the graphic driver ppa to install 430 as 418 is the highest one available in the official repos 
https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=disco&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=nvidia

I'm confused as to why the newer driver (and for that matter 435 which is in the ppa for 18.04) are not available in the newer version of Ubuntu, this seems kinda backwards to me. Is this an oversight or intentional?

Could someone "in the know" explain this to me?

---

the closest I could come to my question was [Why are Nvidia proprietary drivers not visible on Ubuntu 19.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1171071/why-are-nvidia-proprietary-drivers-not-visible-on-ubuntu-19-04) but it doesn't quite address my question and also doesn't have an answer

Comment: omg this is not opinion based it is a legitimate question about  why a *newer* version of Ubuntu would not have the same *newer* drivers available as the older LTS version of Ubuntu.  I didn't say is *should* or *imo it should*  I asked why it didn't have the same drivers available

Comment: noun: opinion:

    a view or judgment formed about something, not necessarily based on fact or knowledge.... I was asking for ***fact*** and ***knowledge** not a ***judgement***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 19.04 will reach End of Life in 3 months, so it makes no sence to update the driver in reposiroies. It is available in PPA.

You will be able to upgrade to 19.10 in a month or two, where you'll get the latest driver.

18.04 is LTS and will last for many years. That's why it got the update.

Comment: ok that makes sense in that respect but does it not make more sense to keep it updated for users who need the newer drivers for newer hardware?  I installed a rtx 2070 super and it made installation a bit of a challenge. Luckily knew to install in safe graphics mode then add the ppa to get the current drivers.  Would that not drive potential new users away like a plague if their first attempt at a Linux install was a nightmare?

Comment: especially when there is a box to tick to "automatically install restricted drivers" specifically to make this kind of install smooth, but it fails b/c the needed drivers are not available?

Comment: 19.04 is a testing release for experienced users, not for first time users. So nobody really cares.

Comment: OK fair enough, thank for the answer.  The ***fact based answer***  sorry for the snark but immediate close vote on dubious grounds rather annoys me(see my comments in the OP for reference) question answered and will be accepted when possible

Comment: Close votes are because it is opinion based. This is the fact that the driver doesn't exist. We can only guess why.

Comment: ehh I was not asking for a guess, *someone* knows. If that person decides to answer or not is debatable

Comment: You can't find people who make these decisions here. We all are users.

Comment: point taken, but there is no way afaik to get to those people directly so this is the only platform to ask that I know of.

Comment: There is a way to get to those people. But it is rather an unimportant reason to do it. Maybe someone forgot or didn't have time to pack the drivers. And in a couple of months it will be obolete. So it is not worth the effort.